# Add Additional Text when repeated group header present in Birt Report

Tags: reporting, birt

Using BIRT 3.2.22

In my reports I need to conditionally display some text if the same Group Header is repeated. The repeating Group Header should show some text like 'Continued...'

I followed article mentioned below that doesn't help me to resolve the issue.
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/157862/

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the old forum entry you mentioned in your question, it is probably necessary to use separate RunTask and RenderTask to make this work.
I never tried something like this myself.